# Replacing old motherboard with new motherboard in same tower?

Tags: motherboard

I have an old tower that houses an ASUS P6T Deluxe V2 motherboard. I want to know if a new ASUS Prime Z390-A motherboard would fit in the same tower. I'm trying to build a new computer but save cost by recycling old parts where possible. The old tower is a good size but has no real info. All it says it is an Antec design.

Comment: Grab both mobo manuals and compare the form factor sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Motherboards come in a few standard form factors (sizes). According to [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813119152), the ASUS Prime Z390-A has an ATX form factor as does the ASUS P6T Deluxe V2. As they have the same form factors, they should physically fit in the same case.

Comment: I would agree with you Blackwood. This answer, answers the question, and should not be a comment.

Comment: Blackwood, I'm sure that the entire community appreciates the time and effort you devote towards the **Suggested Edits** queue, since it noticeably improves the quality of the Super User realm!  However, I think you may be getting just a bit carried away with your decisions to `Edit` rather than `Approve` or `Reject` the suggestions.  [This](https://superuser.com/posts/1386089/revisions) seems to be the most prominent example:  did we *really* need to edit just to take out the word "Basically"...?  That seems to be rather trivial, at best.

Comment: @Run5k I chose the option to "Improve edit" which approves the suggested edit (awarding the original editor 2 points) and allows for small improvements at the same time. While I wouldn't have made such a small edit on its own, there seems to be no harm in making it part of a somewhat larger edit that would be approved in any case.

Comment: Please, don't get me wrong. Your overall contributions are terrific! However, that really wasn't one of them. I know that "Improve edit" automatically accepts the suggestion, but that's part of the problem: you are eliminating the consensus best 2-of-3 votes process when you do that, and you don't *know* that it would have been approved in any case... the other two voters may have selected "Reject."  Realistically, the "Improve edit" function is there for significant improvements to the question/answer.  Honestly, eliminating the word "Basically" did nothing to improve the text.